# Which is propagated first? Direct Event vs Listener

Tags: extjs, event-handling, ext.net

Given the case i have any Ext-Element and i declare:

```
<ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnDirectClick="someMethod" OnClick="someFunction />
```

or

```
<ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server">
  <Listeners> <Click Handler="someFunction" /> </Listeners>
  <DirectEvents> <Click Method="someMethod" /> </DirectEvents>
</Buttons>
```

which will be called first? someFunction or someMethod. and could one use variables set by someFunction in someMethod, and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both events will be called at basically the exact same time. Which one fires first may vary.

Configuring two event handlers for the same event is not recommended. If you provide more information regarding your requirements, I could offer some suggestions.

It might be better to use the `.Before` and `.Success` (and `.Failure`) handlers of the `<Click>` DirectEvent if you want to run some client-side code before or after the DirectEvent is called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to call fuction when `DirectEvents.Click.Success` ?